# Out of troubleshooting ideas: drop1( ) returns an error on one computer but not another

Tags: r

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. I wrote a piece of code and it works fine on my computer (and multiple others) but when my supervisor runs it on his computer everything works except the drop1( ) command.

My data and code are as follows:

```
Data frame structure (condensed)
> str(Df)
'data.frame':   96 obs. of  13 variables:

 $ BWA   : Factor w/ 3 levels "L","M","H": 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ SBW   : int  25 50 75 100 25 50 75 100 25 50 ...
 $ LS    : num  -0.16 0.137 0.028 0.044 -0.26 ...
 $ Def   : num  0.1316 0.4304 0.0338 0.1668 -0.1398 ...
 $ fSite  : Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

M1<-gls(LS ~ 1+SBW+BWA,method='ML')

M2<-lme(LS~ 1 + SBW+BWA, random= ~1|fSite,method='ML')
drop1(M1,test='Chisq')
drop1(M2,test='Chisq')
```

I get

> drop1(M1, test='Chisq')

```
>Single term deletions

>Model:
> LS ~ 1 + SBW + BWA
>     Df     AIC     LRT Pr(>Chi)   
> <none>    -156.00                    
> SBW     1 -151.48  6.5166 0.010687 * 
> BWA     2 -148.43 11.5711 0.003072 **
---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

(and similar output for drop1(M2))

however my supervisor gets:

> drop1(M1, test='Chisq')

```
> Error in terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute
```

To troubleshoot the problem I've tried my code file on multiple computers (Macs and PCs) with various versions of R. Every time the drop1() command worked fine. So I know it's an issue with this one specific computer and not a problem with my code.

On the troublesome computer I tired to fix the problem by:

- running various different models in the drop1() command (including models fit with lmer, lme & gls)
- updating R and its packages
- a complete uninstall and reinstall of R

No matter what I do I can't get drop1(  ) to work.

Does anybody have any ideas why a basic command like drop1(  ) would not work on this one computer. If anyone can see something here that I'm missing or suggest another way to troubleshoot this problem please let me know.

Comment: did you examine the str of M1 on both pcs, particularly the `M1$terms`? Try R --vanilla?

Comment: check out `sessionInfo()` in both places (and post it here)?  Make sure you're running with `R CMD BATCH --vanilla` when troubleshooting on your advisor's machine?  Post results of `traceback()`?

Comment: More than one package may have a drop1 command, resulting in name clash.  Use the syntax package::drop1, ie stats::drop1 instead of just drop1 to select the right package.  Install the package sos and use findFn("drop1").  The difference may be in the rprofile.site file loading different libraries at startup.